# Install PROC LCA SAS

Tags: sas

someone have some idea about how to install PROC LCA?

The only download mirror I can find is this one: https://www.methodology.psu.edu/downloads/proclcalta/
but actually it doesn't work (file not found).

Someone knows how I can install it?

Comment: Just as an FYI this is only valid on Windows machine with a full SAS installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link [SAS Procedures for Latent Class Analysis & Latent Transition Analysis (PROC LCA)](https://scholarsphere.psu.edu/resources/64f9c5c9-dc4b-48f3-9628-92b36b7cf075) by getting to their new website at https://www.methodology.psu.edu/research-and-rigor/ and clicking on the link [software developed at The Methodology Center](https://scholarsphere.psu.edu/catalog?button=&search_field=creator&q=methodology%20center&button=).